# How to write result of regular expression variable into new file using perl?

Tags: perl

From the below code I want to store the regular expression result variable contents (i.e $fh result into new file name ). How can I do it?

Is there any possible way  to do get regex variable output (i.e `$fh` output) written in new file?
Here is my code :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open my $fh,'<',"open.txt" or die "$!";
while(<$fh>)
  {
    $fh=s/("\d+|\d+|")\s*/$1/g;
    print $fh;
  }
close $fh;
```

Error:

```
readline() on unopened filehandle 1 at fr.pl line 7.
close() on unopened filehandle 1 at fr.pl line 9.
```

Open.txt

```
1
2
3
radio
vendor
version114
version115
```

Output:

Note:
$fh has regular expression values.Now those $fh values  should be stored in new file and print the same contents as like below.

```
radio
vendor
version
version
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include example input and output. What do you want to do? Your regex is strange. You are capturing `"\d+` or `\d+` or `"` (one double quote). Then there is optional whitespace, and you replace all of that with the capture. Do you want `$word` to be the altered line, or the thing inside the capture group?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44674653/edit) to fix the obvious syntax error (that the syntax highlighting is making very clear!) While you're there, you might consider fixing the indentation too. If you want a large number of strangers to read and understand your code, you can help them by making it as easy to follow as possible.

Comment: syntax error fixed and also added indentation. @DaveCross

Comment: Wow. That's a *lot* of indentation :-) You should also take note of @simbabque's requests as without the clarification he asks for, it's going to be hard to answer your question.

Comment: added my input and output part along with the error @DaveCross

Comment: Thanks. Now this is a good question. Please add `$!` to your error handling to see the real error message.

Comment: @simbabque: Oh, the file is opened successfully. The problem is a little more subtle than that. See my answer :-)

Comment: @DaveCross indeed. I didn't see that part. In [the original code before the indentation edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44674653/1) that was `my $word`, not `$fh`.

Comment: @DaveCross also are you not at TPC?

Comment: @simbabque: No, I've never been to The Conference Formerly Known As YAPC in the US. And I'm not about to start while border control is (potentially) asking for laptop/phone passwords.

Comment: @DaveCross ah. Yeah, I agree. I was tempted, but that was one of the main reasons for me not to go. Anyway, come to the German Perl Workshop next week in Hamburg. I promise there will not be a control of that kind on our Schengen border (I don't know what your guys are doing nowadays though).

Comment: You've asked more or less the same question as last time, and the problem is the same - you cannot 'overwrite' a file handle like that.

Comment: Imagine you have a box full of toys. What you want to do is replace one toy at a time. What you are doing is taking the first toy, changing it to some new toy, and then throwing away the whole box and only keeping the new toy.

Comment: Please clearify whether you want (like title says) to write into a **new** file or you want to change something in the same file you have opened.

Comment: When the file writing/overwriting problem is solved, what do you expect your regex replacement to achieve? To me it reads like replace a or b or c (of which only b will ever occur in your input file) and any number of white space, by b. That would not turn your sample input into your desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do. But I can see what is generating your errors. The problem is this line:

```
$fh=s/("\d+|\d+|")\s*/$1/g;
```

Before you execute this line of code, `$fh` contains the filehandle that you are reading data from. But with this line of code, you overwrite that value with the results from your substitution. That's either going to be the number of substitutions made (which is an integer) or an empty string (if the substitution fails). In either of those two cases, `$fh` will no longer contain your filehandle.

So at the end of the first iteration of the loop, `$fh` no longer contains a filehandle. So when you execute `while (<$fh>)` at the start of the second iteration, that will fail (because, as the error says, `$fh` is not an open filehandle). That read fails and the loop is skipped. The next line executed is the call the `close()`. And that also fails for exactly the same reason.

I'm not at all sure what you think that line of code is doing. But what it's **actually** doing is breaking your program :-)

**Update:** I suspect that reading (and, more importantly, understanding) the Perl FAQ [How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2C-delete%2C-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2C-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3F) will be a very profitable use of your time at this point. It looks like you don't understand how basic file manipulation works.

Comment: The think is i want to remove all the digits from the file using that regular expression.After removing digits the output should be written in new file name. @Dave Cross

Comment: @salar33: Ok. And why do you think that overwriting your filehandle is a good way to achieve that?

Comment: Because i want to use same file handle and perform some other operations in such case i feel it will be better if it overwrites the same file handle .@Dave Cross

Comment: @salar33: But, you're overwriting a filehandle with an integer. That's never going to work.

Comment: Then how can i do by overwriting the same filehandle and use the same file handle to save its contents in new file name. @DaveCross