# How to pass local variable as the `while` condition

Tags: perl

Here in my code I have tried to pass a variable `$result` inside the `while` loop condition.

How can I do it?

#### My code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;
my $output="/data/file.txt";
my @files=File::Find::Rule->file ->in($output);
foreach my $file(@files)
{
    my ($file)=~m|(.*)|;
    my $outfile="$file.txt";
    open my $fh_out,'>',$outfile or die "error";
    open my $fh,'<',$file or die "error";
    while(my $line=<$fh>)
         {
           my @data=split/:/,$line);
           for my $result(@data)
               {
                if(-f $outfile)
                   {
                    open my $fh1,'<',$result || die "$!";
                    $result=~s/("\S+|\S+")\s*/$1/g;
                    
                    while($result)##Note:Error at this part $result from local variable should pass as loop condition.Then only it will print $result statement inside the while loop.Now the print $result is not printing.
                        {
                        $result.=$_;
                        print $result;
                        }
                       push @data,$fh1;
                      }
                }
          }
   }
```

In my code `@data` contents can be stored as local variable `$result`.

Now the same `$result` contents should be used in `while` condition.

How can I do it?

Is there any other way to use with file handle?

#### The input file: `$file`

```
sync_logic : a
symbol1: b
symbol2: c
symbol3: d
```

#### `@data` will have the following contents

```
'sync_logic', 'a'
'symbol1',    'b'
'symbol2',    'c'
'symbol3',    'd'
```

#### The expected output from `$result` should be as follows

```
sync_logic a
symbol1 b
symbol2 c
symbol3 d
```

Error:

```
I got the following error message when i run the above code:

Killed
```

Comment: You assign an empty string to `$result` with the line `$result = "";`.  Then you attempt to read from that? It's an empty string.  It's not even a valid filehandle.  If your `@data` contains filehandles just remove `$result = "";` and see what happens. If the `@data` does _not_ in fact have filehandles then I have no idea what you are trying to do, please explain.

Comment: Am trying to pass $result into while condition to read the contents of $result line by line.So i had tried the above code.But am not sure is it right manner to pass local variable as file while loop condition. @zdim

Comment: I understand that part.  Yes, you can do that, exactly as written, now once you've edited and commented out that line.  Did you try what is posted now?  I don't know what `$out` is, and I don't know whether `@data` carries valid lexical filehandles -- but if all that is alright the posted code as it is now should work.

Comment: Just in case:  I take it that your `@data` contains valid opened filehandles (things that you get with `open my $fh, '<', $file` or such).  Then the shown code should work as it stands.  But, the part of the question where you show `@data` and expected output isn't clear to me.  Does your `@data` have  filehandles and what happens with the code as it is now?

Comment: while(<$result>) is breaking in my case.I dont know how to pass $result variable into while loop condition .@zdim

Comment: if i run the above code i got the message as killed in my terminal .@zdim

Comment: i want to use same local variable as while condition and print the same contents of local variable i.e $result inside the while loop @zdim

Comment: Since I am not sure what is going on I posted a working example.  Let me know.

Comment: added input file for your reference @zdim

Comment: Let me summarize what I see.  You have a file with text like `symbol1:`. You read that and store text in `@data`.  Then you iterate over data and for each `$result` you want to do `<$result>`.  As I said, `<>` is an operator which needs a _filehandle_ to read from, not just a string with some text.  So I don't understand what you are expecting from `<$result>` -- can you explain this?  I will remove my answer now since it doesn't apply to the question as it stands at the moment.  I will edit and restore the answer later, if it can be made to fit the explained problem.

Comment: that is what am questioning is it right manner to pass the local variable inside the while loop condition. @zdim

Comment: Yes, it is right.  But the `<$result>` does not make any sense if that `$result` is merely some text, like `symbol1`.  If you can explain what you expect  the `<$result>` to do (and what that `symbol1` means etc) I will revisit this.  Also, please see again my first three comments.

Comment: i had removed that <> .Now the above code is not printing the expected output. So i raised this question whether $result local variable is passing in correct manner inside the while loop condition. Is this is the right way to do or  i should follow any other ways .@zdim

Comment: By mistake i had include the <> angular brackets.I thought it as an file handle but here i need to pass the local variable as condition .@zdim

Comment: So you are saying that `<>` is a mistake and shouldn't be there?  What about all my questions about it?  Besides, it is not that simple -- `while ($variable)` doesn't make much sense either.  But, yes, you can use a local variable as a condition.

Comment: i think you are not clear with my question my error part is only with while condition.All other things are fine.I want to pass the local variable as while loop condition .i dont know how to pass .So i had posted my question here how to pass the local variable as condition @zdim

Comment: Why do you want to do `while ($result)` or something similar? `$result` is only a scalar containing a string. Just do `for my $result( @data ){ print "result = $result\n" }` instead of your actual `for` loop, and it will print the values of `$result`. Furthermore, do you realize that `@data` never contains more than two elements? Also, what is `$out`?

Comment: Also, I've seen one or two similar questions recently; may I ask if you got this problem while following a tutorial / book ? if so, which is it?

Comment: What you're asking doesn't make much sense. It sounds like you may have used a different language (Ruby perhaps) and are expecting something similar in Perl. If so then it would help a lot if you showed how you would do this in a language that you know well.

Comment: What is `$out` please?

Comment: check my code i had added few more lines $out => $outfile.I hope now you had understood why i had used $outfile @Borodin

Comment: $OUTFILE IS USED TO CHECK THE EXISTENXE OF FILE @Dada

Comment: @salar33: Okay, well I've tidied your code so that I could read it and it's clear it won't compile. You never declare `$output`, your call to `File::Find::Rule` is wrong, and you have a `while ( ... ) { ... } else { ... }` construct which is invalid. Please show your real code.

Comment: You seem to be convince that your problem is "how to pass a local variable as a condition to a while", but it's not. There are many incoherences in your code, and it's really hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. It might help if you could give us some context about what you are trying to do: is it some kind of programming exercise? is there a specification that you are following? (in any cases, please add details). Also, like Borodin suggested, if it's a problem you'd be able to solve with another programing language, show us the code in that other language, it might help us.

Comment: i will reconstruct my code clearly @Dada

Comment: @salar33: *"Am trying to pass $result into while condition to read the contents of $result line by line"* You need to understand that your *outer* `while` loop reads *one line at a time from the file into `$line`. The `split` statement divides that line into two (given your sample data) and puts `sync_logic ` and ` a` into `@data` (for the first line of the file). Then your `for` loop sets `$result` first to `sync_logic ` and then to ` a`. I cannot fathom what your *inner* `while` loop is supposed to do.

Comment: This question makes as little sense as [the one you asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44674653/how-to-write-result-of-regular-expression-variable-into-new-file-using-perl). Unless you can find a way to make your requirements clearer, I'm going to stop trying to answer your questions.

Comment: @salar33: No you haven't. Your code is still random nonsense that doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 2):

As with [yesterday's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44674653/how-to-write-result-of-regular-expression-variable-into-new-file-using-perl), it's really unclear what you are trying to do.

In an attempt to understand what is going on here, I took the part of your code that processes one file and converted it so that it read the data from the DATA filehandle. Cleaning up your strange formatting gave me this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $outfile = 'test.txt';

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
  my @data = split/:/,$line);
  for my $result (@data) {
    if (-f $outfile) {
      open my $fh, '<', $result || die "$!";
      $result=~s/("\S+|\s+")\s*/$1/g;

      while ($result) {
        $result .= $_;
        print $result;
      }
      push @data, $fh;
    }
  }
}

__DATA__
sync_logic : a
symbol1: b
symbol2: c
symbol3: d
```

Running this, gave me an error:

> syntax error at test.pl line 9, near "$line)"

So you're not even giving us code that compiles.

Look. A vital part of being a good programmer is attention to detail. If you are sharing code with people, hoping that they will look at it for you and help you find the problems, then you need to give them code that they can run. Before sharing sample code with us, you need to test it and ensure that it compiles. Do not just edit code on the fly in the SO editor and expect that it will still work. We don't want to spend time fixing your typos - we want to help you fix the real problems in your code.

So I'm afraid I'm giving up at this point. I will find people to help who don't waste my time.

(And, yes, I know that this isn't strictly an answer to the question, so I expect to be downvoted or have the answer flagged. But while it's not an answer to the question, I do think it's useful information that salar33 needs to hear.)

Comment: why you are using file handle as 
<DATA> @Dave Cross

Comment: you have not opened it anywhere @Dave Cross

Comment: and why you had given different file handle @Dave Cross

Comment: I used DATA because it's a convenient way to include data inside your program and not have to use a separate file. I didn't open it because it's a special filehandle that is already opened for you.

Comment: I know you showed us new code. I've copied your new code, but it still contains syntax errors. That is why I'm giving up helping you.

Comment: Could you please say me where the error occurs because it runs for me expect the error par @Dave Cross

Comment: I've told you. It's in my answer above. Have you read my answer? How much clearer can I make it?

Comment: Its your mistake your added braces at the end of the line @Dave Cross

Comment: It's not about braces, it's about parentheses. This line is still in your code: `my @data=split/:/,$line);`. And at this point, I am going to stop replying to you.

Answer (score 1):

From your expected output, it looks like you just want to remove the colon `:` from each line. That would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $file = 'test.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {

    chomp $line;

    my @data = split /\s*:\s*/, $line;
    print join(' ', @data), "\n";
}
```

Given the input data that you show in your question, that produces this output

#### output

```
sync_logic a
symbol1 b
symbol2 c
symbol3 d
```